# What are these Bahrain insects living in a colony?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image][image]

These insects are in the desert in Bahrain. About 500 in one place both adults and juveniles. Some dung beetle near by. Does anyone know a name?

The adults seem to be protecting the young ?  [image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE! Kindly explain your question further - is it about species identification or what? Currently its hard to get you I am afraid!

Comment: Those are hemipterans (true bugs). It is not uncommon for hemipterans to cluster together.